# Angular query throw error

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to create a simple app to search through some contact and also view items individually... but when I click on a single item I get the following error, I tried to use get instead but when I do so other pages stopped working and '/:id' list all the constant.

**Error**: [$resource:badcfg] : [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$resource/badcfg?p0=Error%20in%20resource%20configuration%20for%20action%20%60%7B0%7D%60.%20Expected%20response%20to%20contain%20an%20%7B1%7D%20but%20got%20an%20%7B2%7D&p1=query&p2=array&p3=object)

Error in resource configuration for action `Error in resource configuration for action`{0}`. Expected response to contain an {1} but got an {2}`. Expected response to contain an query but got an array (Request: object {4})

```
var app = angular.module("Charts", ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        //Route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : '/portal/assets/templates/list.html',
            controller  : 'ChartsCtrl'
        }).when('/:id', {
            templateUrl : '/portal/assets/templates/single.html',
            controller  : 'ChartsCtrl'
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
            enabled: false,
            requireBase: false
        });
});

app.factory('Charts', function ($resource) {

    return $resource('/portal/charts/json/:id',{ id: '@id' });

});

app.controller('ChartsCtrl', function($scope, Charts, $routeParams, $location, $filter) {

    var id = $routeParams.id;
    var charts = Charts.query({'id':id});
    $scope.charts = charts;

});
```

Comment: It seems like you're trying to use the same controller for both the list and detail views. But that doesn't make sense w/the code you've shown. In the "list" case, passing an ID to the controller doesn't make sense, but it makes perfect sense when you're showing an individual item. Try it w/two separate controllers, and later you can worry (if it still makes sense) about refactoring it into one controller.

Comment: @SunilD. no difference, either way I have a problem with viewing a single query.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way that you might do it w/separate controllers:

```
// Controller for the list view
app.controller('ChartsCtrl', function($scope, Charts) {
    $scope.charts = Charts.query();
});

// Controller for the detail view, edit your route definition to use this
app.controller('ChartDetailCtrl', function($scope, Charts, $routeParams) {
    var id = $routeParams.id;
    $scope.chart = Charts.get({id: id});
});
```

This way each controller knows how to get the data it needs.